# Difference between clojure and clojurescript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Can anyone please list some differences between Clojure and ClojureScript? (Please and thank you) Syntax wise differences?

Comment: Would you be willing to edit the question to focus on a specific area of comparison between the two languages. Something specific enough to have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are different languages with a common syntax that are hosted in different environments.

Answer (score 15):

The full differences between Clojure and ClojureScript are listed in detail [here on the ClojureScript website.](https://clojurescript.org/about/differences)

According to that page, the primary differences lie in:

- concurrent programming
- hosting env (JVM vs a JS VM or Google's Clojure compiler)
- numbers
- characters
- the read, and read-string methods are defined in a different place
- load, and load-file only exist as special REPL functions
- a few of the special forms aren't implemented